# Virtual Device supporting Google Maps API in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, maps

I have a different setup than the tutorials I have been seeing for the Android
SDK. I am trying to setup a virtual device that is compatible with the Google
Maps API. I have three areas I need to fill out: the device and the target (the
tutorials only show a target) and the CPU.

I have put Google APIs - API Level 17 as the target but I don't know what to put for device to get it to work.

I don't know what to put for device and CPU to get it to work.

Here is my log output:
11-17 00:12:38.403: W/ActivityManager(163): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/GoogleMapsWithAndroid.apk
11-17 00:12:38.443: W/ActivityManager(163): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/GoogleMapsWithAndroid.apk
11-17 00:12:38.633: I/PackageManager(163): Removing non-system package:com.example.googlemapswithandroid
11-17 00:12:38.633: I/ActivityManager(163): Force stopping package com.example.googlemapswithandroid uid=10044
11-17 00:12:38.794: I/dalvikvm(163): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
11-17 00:12:38.904: E/PackageManager(163): Package com.example.googlemapswithandroid requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
11-17 00:12:38.913: W/PackageManager(163): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.example.googlemapswithandroid-1.apk
11-17 00:12:38.923: I/ActivityManager(163): Force stopping package com.example.googlemapswithandroid uid=10044
11-17 00:12:38.980: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.contacts
11-17 00:12:38.983: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
11-17 00:12:38.993: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_BIND in package com.android.phone
11-17 00:12:38.993: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.calendar
11-17 00:12:38.993: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cl in package com.android.providers.calendar
11-17 00:12:38.993: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.calendar
11-17 00:12:39.003: W/PackageManager(163): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
11-17 00:12:39.003: W/PackageManager(163): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be44)
11-17 00:12:39.023: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.contacts
11-17 00:12:39.023: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cp in package com.android.providers.contacts
11-17 00:12:39.023: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
11-17 00:12:39.053: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
11-17 00:12:39.053: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
11-17 00:12:39.063: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
11-17 00:12:39.063: W/PackageManager(163): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
11-17 00:12:39.063: W/PackageManager(163): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be45)

Here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0DGP89WIBvLjp6nNjqHdbvaaS71ITKsLNbPZV_g"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapswithandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemapswithandroid.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
         </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So are you following this guide https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/#avdsetup have you added the <uses-library> tag to your AndroidManifest ?

Comment: I did have that and then I took it out after I saw another post that said to remove it to fix an error I was getting about requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps failing

Comment: You should definitely have that line in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: Sorry. i miss edited the previous comment. Now that you formatted the logcat, it does look like something is missing.

Comment: Just got exactly the same stacktrace because of not having the following line in the AndroidManifest.xml inside the <application> tag <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> . Tested on a galaxy nexus running 4.2

Comment: After re-adding the uses library tag I get the error I mentioned above about a shared library being unavailable. I have attached the log for when that is included and have also provided my manifest file as an edit to the initial question. I sincerely appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just experienced this issue because of a wrong usage of the AVD creator.

If you select the AVD Target before selecting the Device, the target will be overwrite with the device default Target.

I thought i had created a Google Apis 17 target, when actually it was a Android 14 without google maps.

I would double check the AVD configuration just to make sure you didn't fall into the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am having trouble getting any of the virtual devices to work but I did get one up at one point and got an error detailed here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39723 so I may be stuck with that bug. Thanks again for the help